# Help with Chinese Tea Identification

Tags: translation

[image]This was a gift.  I have seen how to extract with a needle/knife, but since there is no English at all, I’m at a complete loss to identify this other than that is is Pu-erh.  A friend brought it from China.

[image]

Comment: What else do you want to know besides it being a Pu-erh tea? You can check wikipedia for further information.

Comment: I agree that it's not particularly clear what's being asked here: would it be possible to [edit] to say precisely what someone should write in an answer?  There's many people here who can and will help, but nobody enjoys mindlessly transcribing manufacturing details.

Answer (score 0):

The inside box and scrunched up paper are hard to read because of the angle that the photo was taken from.

**inside box**: the stuff on the right says organic pu-er tea and then a marketing sort of description about the tea being made in a traditional way and how's it natural and tastes good

**scrunched up paper**: has a bunch of product details, net weight, storage instructions, product code, where the factory is. The tea is from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pu%27er_City

**last picture**: basically just logo stuff. It tells you again that it's pu'er tea.

A better picture would help if you have more specific questions!

You can also play around with google translate. They have an option to use your camera to automatically translate Chinese. It's not always the most accurate but it's sort of fun to play around with and will probably be able to give you a general idea of what it says. https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142483?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid